# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier behavior changed for prototype cells?

Tags: iphone, ios5, tableview, storyboard, cells

In iOS5, using ARC and prototype cells for tableView on storyboard, can I replace the code below:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
      initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
return cell;
```

With this simple code??:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
return cell;
```

I saw this on this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Thank's in advance!

Arildo

Answer (score 8):

Sure, your code are right, storyboard automaticaly alloc new cells, this code work great:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    RoadbookCell *cell = (RoadbookCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RoadbookCell"];

    //Configure cell
    //[cell.lab1 setText:@"Test"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't get why, but this thing doesn't work for me. I keep getting a "nil" cell. I create a new master-detail project. The example works great. When I add the cellForRowIndexPath method and table size method and set the size to be 2 I get an exception, since the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier keep getting me "nil".

Comment: have you configured the tableCell in the storyboard? Like this: [link]http://minus.com/m59pfEOqW (note: the cell identifier is the same in storyboard and in cellForRowAtIndexPath)

Comment: And remember you should do any setup stuff in the cell subclass in the "awakeFromNib" method, not "initWithStyle:" (it doesn't get called) since it loads from the storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way Apple intends it to be used, but I recommend against it.  There is a bug that causes dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to return nil when VoiceAssist is enabled on a device.  That means your app will crash for users with this option turned on.  This is still a problem as of iOS 5.1.1

You can find more info and a workaround here:

http://hsoienterprises.com/2012/02/05/uitableview-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-storyboard-and-voiceover-doesnt-work/

The last paragraph has the work-around