# generic subtitle prototype style works but custom prototype doesn't

Tags: objective-c

I have looked at code from the following links:

[Why do my prototype cells show up blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779155/why-do-my-prototype-cells-show-up-blank)

as well as from the tutorial on www.techtopia.com for using custom table view prototypes:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells

But I'm still having my root view show up blank.

I have set up the methods to log the receipt of data from my XML parser delegate, and I know
the data is coming in, but for some reason, unless I use one of the default styles (subtitle, et cetera) I'm unable to use a custom prototype that I built myself.

Here's my sample code:

For the custom UITableViewCell Class (TickerListViewCell.h):

```
#import "TickerListViewCell.h"

@implementation TickerListViewCell

@synthesize ticker = _ticker;
@synthesize companyName = _companyName;
@synthesize price = _price;

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

(TickerListViewCell.m)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TickerListViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ticker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *companyName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *price;


@end
```

(TickerListViewController.m)
...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomStockCell";

TickerListViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[TickerListViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomStockCell"];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

// Configure the cell...

self.currentStock = [self.mystocks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

cell.ticker.text = self.currentStock.symbol;
cell.companyName.text = self.currentStock.companyName;
cell.price.text = [self.currentStock.askRealtime stringValue];

NSLog(@"Configured cell for stock: %@",[(Stock *)[self.mystocks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] symbol]);
return cell;
}
```

...

I believe the issue is happening within the call to "cellForRowAtIndexPath" because when I change the prototype to a generic subtitle one, it works, but it fails with my custom prototype. Bear in mind that I also made sure the class for the prototype cell was mapped to my custom class.

I've tried taking out the "if (cell == nil)" block as some tutorials indicated, but that didn't solve the problem. The code did not show any error pre-compilation but generated one once I tried to run it in the iOS 6 simulator without that block.

Any help is appreciated. I'm at my wits end now.

Comment: I hadn't gotten a response on this in a while, but just as an update, I moved on to using Phone Gap instead for my mobile app development. I am currently working on the android platform, and will return to this once I start working on the iOS version of my first App.