# Programmatically adding a UITableView - how do I set the reuse identifier for the cells?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that at some point grows a UITableView, and when it does I simply init the TableView instance variable and add it to the view, but I'm not sure how to handle the dequeueing of cells to add to the view; I need a reuse identifier, but I'm not sure how to set it.

What do I do within this method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"wot";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You do the same thing you'd do in any implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Nothing about the way you obtained the table view changes the way a table view works. The code you've shown is a perfectly good start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the method `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`

1. check if `cell` exists
2. If it doesn't, then you need to initialize it.

code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"wot";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: someStyle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: from iOS 5 on you don't need to check for `!cell`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946840/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-behavior-changed-for-prototype-cells

Comment: Since unlike with IB where I can give all cells a specific layout with UIViews on it (UILabel, UIImage, etc.) do I have to create a UILabel and add it to the cell's subview for each cell?

Comment: You can create a subclass of UITableViewCell and do the specific subview setup there.

Comment: If you use Gabriele's suggestion, you need to register your subclassed UITableViewCell's class with the table view with the `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method.

Answer (score 0):

The reuse identifier need not be explicitly defined.In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method the definitions you included in question is enough to work with

for [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW4)

Eg

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]];
    }
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    TimeZoneWrapper *timeZoneWrapper = [region.timeZoneWrappers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = timeZoneWrapper.localeName;
    return cell;
}
```